# Inserir dados de um array em um banco mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, array

Recebo um json de uma aplicação android. Esse json é uma classe java que foi convertida com Gson do java para uma string. Apos o web server em php receber esse json eu converto para uma array.

Quero fazer um insert genérico no meu web server, onde que automaticamente ele percorre o array e insere na tabela passada por parâmetro.

ex:

```
public function create($array){

    /*
     * O nome da tabela é recebida por um post e é passada por um construtor
     * $condição: Aqui eu teria que pegar os nomes das keys e deixar assim por exempo: nome, idade, sexo
     * $valores: tenho que pegar o conteudo dos arrays. Ai tenho que verificar se é uma string ou data ou float para deixar entre aspas.Ex: 'rafael', 18, '1987-12-12'
    */
    $query = "INSERT INTO $this->tabela ( $condicao ) VALUES ( $valores )";

    $flag = mysqli_query($this->con, $query);

    if($flag === TRUE){
        $json['flag'] = TRUE;
    } else {
        $json['flag'] = FALSE;
    }

    mysqli_close($this->con);
    return $json;

}
```

não sei se tem uma maneira mais fácil de fazer isso que pretendo, ou se existe alguma api pronta.

Toda ajuda é bem vinda!

Comment: Por que você converte os dados JSON para Array? Por que não inserir os dados do json direto no banco de dados? É muito mais simples.

Comment: Porque tenho relacionamentos no banco de dados.

Comment: Como assim relacionamentos? Pode explicar e dar um exemplo?

Comment: por exemplo: um paciente tem um tipo e também é relacionado com pagamento. Como eu faria esse relacionamento entre eles?

Comment: esses relacionamentos você criar no próprio banco de dados. Através do Inner Join ( left join, full outer join) . Desse jeito quando você aplicar um select, você poderá obter resultados relacionados. Eu poderia responder melhor, mas isso sairia do tema da sua pergunta.

Comment: mas eu teria que ter o conceito de chaves no banco... se eu tiver uma tabela Paciente com um campo json onde salvo o json paciente, e outra tabela Pagamento tambem com um campo json onde salvo o json pagamento. caso eu precise listar todos os pagamentos que um certo paciente fez, como irei fazer esse filtro?

Comment: E acho que não foge do tema, pois você esta propondo uma nova solução para o meu problema. Pelome nos penso assim.

Comment: Então eu posso enviar uma resposta dizendo que seria melhor você utilizar o próprio objeto JSON? Eu recomendo você abrir uma nova pergunta quanto aos relacionamos de Banco de dados, porque com certeza eu vou receber uma flag se eu responder.

Comment: Acho que isso daí vai te abrir uma falha de segurança. Veja isso: [*Mass assignment vulnerability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_assignment_vulnerability) e isso: [*SQL injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como salvar array em db?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204760/como-salvar-array-em-db)

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode usar um código como este, é um modelo para vc ter uma base

```
$campos      = implode(', ', array_keys($array));
$valores     = '"'.implode('", "', $array).'"'; 
$query       = "INSERT INTO $this->tabela 
                              ( $campos ) 
                       VALUES ( $valores )";
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma sugestão para solucionar seu problema. Você disse que precisa recuperar os valores de um JSON e que para isso deseja transforma-los em array.

Existe uma função no PHP, que recupera dados de um JSON e os transforma em objetos.

Segue um exemplo

```
$obj = json_decode($json_recebido);

echo "nome: " . $obj->$nome . " idade: " $obj->$idade . " sexo: " . $obj->sexo;
```