# Como salvar array em db?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, array

Possuo 4 campos e desejo salvar em um db, no entanto ao colocar em foreach ($_post['nome'] as $nome)... eu não sei como faço para adicionar mais..

```
**DB**
id | vt | nome | qtn | id_cat
1  | 23 | qua..| 58  | 4
2  | 36 | não..| 57  | 2
```

**cadastro**

```
<form action="php/cad.php" method="post">
    <label>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="add" value="Add" />
    </label>
    <label>vt:</label>

    <fieldset id="inputs_adicionais"></fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="btn btn-default">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var input = '<label>Nome: <input type="text" name="vt[]" /> <input type="text" name="nome[]" placeholder="Nome"> <input type="text" name="qtn[]"  placeholder="Qtn"> <input type="text" name="id_cat[]" placeholder="id cat"> <a href="#" class="remove">X</a></label>';

        $("input[name='add']").click(function( e ){
            $('#inputs_adicionais').append( input );
        });

        $('#inputs_adicionais').delegate('a','click',function( e ){
            e.preventDefault();
            $( this ).parent('label').remove();
        });

    });
</script>
```

**cadastro no db**

```
<?php
    include "conexao.php";

    $vt = $_POST['vt'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $qtn = $_POST['qtn'];
    $id_cat = $_POST['id_cat'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO produto(vt, nome, qtn, id_cat) VALUES ('$vt', '$nome', '$qtn', '$id_cat')";
    $query = $con->query($sql);

    if($query!=null){
        print "<script>window.location='../inicio.php';</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Nao entendi, poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Adicionei o código completo. Tenho vários campos para add e eu gostaria de fazer isso sem precisar ficar cadastrando 1 por 1, por isso preciso cadastrar vários e clicar apenas 1 vez em "Cadastrar".

Comment: Vai gravar um nome por registro ou vai gravar todos em um coluna só (não é uma boa ideia)

Comment: **DB:id | vt | nome | qtn | id_cat** Vai ser criada nova coluna com seu respectivo vt, nome, qtn, id_cat..Em um formulário eu vou inserir -> vt, nome,qtn,id_car, clico para add mais e add mais -> vt,nome.... Depois eu cadastro todos de uma vez, cada um em sua respectiva coluna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exemplo de como montar um insert com múltiplos valores ao invés de gerar um insert para cada repetição do laço.

Comentários do que faz o script estão embutidos no código.

Note que não há validação do recebimento do $_POST pois esse não é o foco da questão, mas sugiro que faça um tratamento mínimo para evitar erros.

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";

/*
O laço de repetição prioriza o campo "nome". Se existir outro campo com um array maior, os arrays excedentes em relação aos arrays do campo "nome" serão ignorados.

Isso não é uma regra geral. É apenas um exemplo de como poderá tratar os dados.
*/ 
foreach ($_POST['nome'] as $k => $v) {
    $p = 'vt';
    // Se vt for não existir nesse índice do array, receberá valor vazio
    if (!isset($_POST[$p][$k])) {
        $_POST[$p][$k] = '';
    }
    $$p = $_POST[$p][$k];

    $p = 'qtn';
    // Se qtn for não existir nesse índice do array, receberá valor ZERO
    if (!isset($_POST[$p][$k])) {
        $_POST[$p][$k] = '0';
    }
    $$p = $_POST[$p][$k];

    $p = 'id_cat';
    // Se id_cat for não existir nesse índice do array, receberá valor vazio
    if (!isset($_POST[$p][$k])) {
        $_POST[$p][$k] = '';
    }
    $$p = $_POST[$p][$k];

    $values[] = "('$vt', '$v', '$qtn', '$id_cat')";
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO produto(vt, nome, qtn, id_cat) VALUES  '.implode(PHP_EOL.', ', $values);

$query = $con->query($sql);
if($query!=null){
    print "<script>window.location='../inicio.php';</script>";
}
?>
```